# Функция перехода в расширенный редактор кода, чтобы подсасывала существующий код

Tags: предложение, сниппеты, редактор

Я набрал код в расширенном редакторе, отладил, протестировал, вставил в сообщение. А потом снова хочу отредактировать в расширенном редакторе. А нету такой функции, приходится либо ухищряться и копировать через блокнот, либо просто не пользоваться для редактирования расширенным редактором.

Хорошо бы сделать кнопку для того что бы взять код из ответа или сообщения и закинуть в расширенный редактор.

Можно все блоки кода что бы имели свои номера скажем, и при открытии редактора предлагалось выбрать код из списка уже существующих, если такой код есть.

**UPDATED:**

Или можно так. Когда курсор установлен на текущий код, то при клике на "фрагмент кода" в редакторе открывался именно код на котором стоит курсор.

Comment: Что такое «расширенный редактор»?

Comment: @alexolut, редактор сниппетов? Больше на SO никаких редакторов кода вроде и нет.

Comment: @alexolut "Фрагмент кода на javascript/html/css" кнопка

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Всё там есть:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ого, спасибо, не заметил. Тем не менее при наличае двух фрагментов, как я понял он редактирует последний.

Comment: Нет, он редактирует тот, под которым расположен.

Comment: точно, спасибо, буду знать